# Trim input without blocking space input with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, trim

How can I trim the value of an input without blocking the input of a space letter?

for example if I write or past an copy `" hello world "` it should be corrected to `"hello world"`

The script I have so far would trim the pasted input correct, but if I write it manually it would block the space letter so that the output would be `"helloworld"`.

```js
$(function(){
    $('.trim').bind('input', function(){
        $(this).val(function(_, v){
            return v.trim();
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="trim" type="text">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try writing on `blur` event, it will remove spaces from the beginning and end of the current text.:

```js
$(function(){
    $('.trim').bind('blur', function(){
        $(this).val(function(_, v){
            return v.trim();
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<input class="trim" type="text">
```

Comment: good idea to use another bind event! I will accept that answer as it suits in my case.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the jquery trim function to trim start and end of the string without changing the words.

$.trim("    **Sample String**    ");